# Any way to catch a contextmenu "Paste" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser

I need to attach some action to the "paste" menu item you get among others in the menu the browser pops up when you copied some text before and then rightclick some input field. Any way to do this other than implement an own whole menu and attach it to the contextmenu event?

Comment: Nice question – I would guess there is no such possibility as per the standard. You can search through [the event reference list at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events) though. Maybe there is some proprietary event.

Comment: So you're not interested in catching the "paste" event that's fired on an `<input>` when something is pasted, is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the closest that you can get is using the `onpaste` event in Javascript.

It catches the contextMenu's `Paste` and also the `Ctrl` + `V` key events.

Here's a demo:

```js
document.getElementById("textbox").onpaste = function(){
  alert("trying to paste something, huh?");
  // do something more
}

document.getElementById("textbox").ondrop = function(){ // user may also try to get the text in the textbox by dragging and dropping
  alert("trying to drag-drop something, huh?");
  // do something more
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="paste something here" id="textbox" />
```

[onpaste documentation | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.onpaste)

Comment: It's a shame that `onpaste` doesn't catch the act of dragging-and-dropping selected text into an input field... although perhaps `ondrop` event may help there?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Very witty comment. Updated my answer!

Comment: In principle this answers my question, unfortunately here (jsf 1.2, richfaces 3.3.2) only the Ctrl+V works, pasting via context menu not.

Comment: @wieland.gmeiner Not familiar with the setup that you have but my code works on the latest Chrome, Firefox and IE. Please share more details so we can help you.

Comment: Thanks, I verified that your code works. Unfortunately I have to work with old versions of jsf and richfaces. What I'm trying to do is to fire a `valueChangeListener` via `a4j:support` on an `h:inputText`. This works with the `keyup` event in the `a4j:support` tag, but not with the `paste` or `drop`.